# comparator for double moving zero's to the back

Tags: java

Hello I'm looking to build a comparator for doubles where I could move the zeros to the back of the list.

example

```
5,2,3,8,0,1
```

I would like it to look like this.

```
1,2,3,5,8,0
```

My compare method

```
private Double[] values;

@Override
public int compare(int slot1, int slot2) {
    final Double val1 = values[slot1];
    final Double val2 = values[slot2];
    if (val1 < val2) return -1;
    if (val1 > val2) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

How do I move the zero's to the back?

Comment: comparing 0 with 0 should be 0. Comparing 0 with anything should be > 0. Comparing anything with 0 should be < 0. You should really be able to turn those simple rules to code by yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not completely following you.

Comment: You want 0 at the back. So 0 should be considered by your comparator as bigger than 1, 2, 3, etc. Bigger than any other double except 0. When `a` is bigger than `b`, a comparator comparing `a` and `b` must return an positive integer. When `a` is lower than `b`, a comparator must return a negative integer.

Comment: What are you going to do if the double value is 0.001?

Comment: I'm setting up price sorting and sometimes people leave the prices as zero. So I guess there could be a chance that it could be 0.01. What should I expect to see if that happens?

Comment: That's the question you have to ask yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    final Integer[] searchList = new Integer[] { 5, 2, 3, 8, 0, 1 };
    Arrays.sort(searchList, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {

            if (o1 == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (o2 == 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
```

Input: `5,2,3,8,0,1`

The result will be:  `1,2,3,5,8,0`

Comment: Might not be stable. If `o1 == o2 == 0`, that should ideally return zero.

Comment: Thank you very much, quick question, is it generally faster to use o1 > o2 vs compareTo? Also would platinum's concern cause real issues?

Comment: I've tested with { 5, 2, 0, 3, 8, 0, 1 }; and works fine it returns:[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 0, 0]

Comment: I ended up going this route, please advise if it's better to use compareTo 
        if (val1 == 0) return 1;
        if (val2 == 0) return -1;
        if (val1 < val2) return -1;
        if (val1 > val2) return 1;
        return 0;

Comment: performance wise, does it matter? The record set is around 100k, so pretty small.

Comment: it is practically the same here is the compareTo source code:  return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);

Comment: Those are nowhere near identical. @PlatinumAzure has it right.

Comment: @HotLicks regarding the speed it does not matter. It is the same.

Comment: Not talking about speed.  What if you have two zeros in the list?

Comment: It works by accident. Your comparator doesn't respect the contract of Comparator, which can lead to all sorts of unexpected results. Why not fix it, which is trivial, instead of hoping that it always works despite blatantly violating the rules?

Comment: @CodeJunkie: you should really figure that out by yourself. It's trivial. What should a comparator return when two values are equal? How to test that two integers are equal to 0?

Comment: Well I understand if the two equal each other to return 0, however isn't that happening in compareTo with this ((x == y) ? 0 : 1)? So it's unclear to me why I would do that again before the compareTo.

Comment: @JB Nizet I understand what you are talking about now. Thanks. if (Objects.equals(o1, o2)) return 0;
        if (o1 == 0) return 1;
        if (o2 == 0) return -1;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it this way
Simply this

```
Double arry[] = {0.0,5.0,2.0,3.0,8.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.1,1.0};
Arrays.sort(arry, new Comparator<Double>() {
    public int compare(Double s1, Double s2) {
        if(s1==0.0)
            return 1;
        else if(s2==0.0)
            return -1;
        else if(s1 == 0.0 && s2 == 0.0)
            return 0;
        else
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arry));
```

or this

```
//first normal sorting
Double arry[] = {0.0,5.0,2.0,3.0,8.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};
Arrays.sort(arry, new Comparator<Double>() {
    public int compare(Double s1, Double s2) {
        if(s1<s2)
            return -1;
        else if(s1>s2)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
});
// push the zeros at the end of the array
int count = 0;
int n =arry.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (arry[i] != 0)
        arry[count++] = arry[i];
while (count < n)
    arry[count++] = 0.0;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arry));
```

Comment: your commend helped me out a lot, been searching for hours!! appreciate it.